# Split or separate uneven/unequal strings with no delimiter

Tags: r, tidyr

Given the dataframe `df`:

```
x <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
y <- c("00L0", "0", "00012L", "0123L0", "0D0")
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

How can I leverage `tidyr::separate` to put each character of the `y` strings into a separate column (one column per string position)?

Desired output:

```
x <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
m1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
m2 <- c(0, NA, 0, 1, "D")
m3 <- c("L", NA, 0, 2, 0)
mN <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(x, m1, m2, m3, mN)
```

Where mN could theoretically go up to m100 (100 columns), or higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works. It fills with blanks rather than `NA`s, but you can change that post-hoc if you prefer. (`fill = 'right'` only works when splitting on a character vector, not explicit positions.)

```
maxchar = max(nchar(as.character(df$y)))
tidyr::separate(df, y, into = paste0("y", 1:maxchar), sep = 1:(maxchar - 1))

#    x y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
# 1 X1  0  0  L  0         
# 2 X2  0                  
# 3 X3  0  0  0  1  2  L   
# 4 X4  0  1  2  3  L  0   
# 5 X5  0  D  0
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a base R method.

```
# split the strings
temp <- strsplit(df$y, split="")
# maximum length of the list items
maxL <- max(sapply(temp, length))
# contstruct data.frame with NAs as fills
temp <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(i) c(i, rep(NA, maxL-length(i))))))

# add to df
df <- cbind(x=df[, -2], temp)
```

which results in

```
        x X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6
1       X1  0    0    L    0 <NA> <NA>
2       X2  0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3       X3  0    0    0    1    2    L
4       X4  0    1    2    3    L    0
5       X5  0    D    0 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I used stringsAFactors=FALSE in the creation of the df:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

But, if I didn't, this code would result in an error as @m0h3n points out. The without this alternative data.frame construction, it is necessary to wrap df$y in `as.character` to coerce the variable from a factor to a character:

```
# split the strings
temp <- strsplit(as.character(df$y), split="")
```

Thanks @m0h3n for pointing this out.

Comment: `as.character(df$y)` should be given for the `strsplit` function, otherwise it fails.

Comment: @m0h3n you are right given the data above. I used stringsAsFactors=FALSE in the `data.frame` function, but I didn't mention this. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string in column y into individual characters using strsplit:

```
> strsplit("00L0",c()) 
[[1]]
[1] "0" "0" "L" "0"
```

Starting with your data frame:

```
> df
   x      y
1 X1   00L0
2 X2      0
3 X3 00012L
4 X4 0123L0
5 X5    0D0
```

I solved the problem of putting these characters into columns by:

First: Use ddply to split all the strings in column y and put these in separate rows

```
> ddply(df, .(x), summarise, v = 1:nchar(as.character(y)), 
        y = unlist(strsplit(as.character(y),c())))
    x v y
1  X1 1 0
2  X1 2 0
3  X1 3 L
4  X1 4 0
5  X2 1 0
6  X3 1 0
7  X3 2 0
8  X3 3 0
9  X3 4 1
10 X3 5 2
11 X3 6 L
12 X4 1 0
13 X4 2 1
14 X4 3 2
15 X4 4 3
16 X4 5 L
17 X4 6 0
18 X5 1 0
19 X5 2 D
20 X5 3 0
```

Second: Use reshape to convert the rows with same x-value into columns

```
> reshape(ans, idvar=c("x"), timevar="v", direction="wide")
    x y.1  y.2  y.3  y.4  y.5  y.6
1  X1   0    0    L    0 <NA> <NA>
5  X2   0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  X3   0    0    0    1    2    L
12 X4   0    1    2    3    L    0
18 X5   0    D    0 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

This may be over-complicating the problem, but it is the only way I could get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `base R` option where we create a delimiter `,` between each character of the 'y' column using `gsub` and then read it with `read.csv`

```
cbind(df[1],read.csv(text=gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ",", df$y, perl=TRUE), 
                header=FALSE,fill=TRUE, na.strings = ""))
#   x V1   V2   V3 V4   V5   V6
#1 X1  0    0    L  0 <NA> <NA>
#2 X2  0 <NA> <NA> NA <NA> <NA>
#3 X3  0    0    0  1    2    L
#4 X4  0    1    2  3    L    0
#5 X5  0    D    0 NA <NA> <NA>
```

---

Or use `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
mxr = max(nchar(as.character(df$y)))
setDT(df)[, paste0("y", seq(mxr)) := tstrsplit(y, "")]
```